# I am having issues finding the range of a function

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have a function as follows

$f(x) = − \sqrt{16 − x^2}$

I have determined the domain to be when the value in the sqrt is $\geq 0$ which is when $x\leq \pm 4$

so to determine the range I have isolated x and got $x=\sqrt{-y^2+16}$

so the answer would then be $y\leq \pm 4$

... its not right, and I am not sure where I am going wrong with this, thanks for your time.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Note that $\sqrt{q}$ denotes the positive square root of $q$

Comment: sorry can you clarify what you mean?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner : ... the *nonnegative* square root of $q$.

Comment: I'm confused about when we add the +/- .... for example y^2=16 , when I square both sides, i add +/- 4, I am not 100% sure why, but was told to , am I getting it wrong here? should it be +/- ONLY if there is a variable?

Comment: BTW $x \le \pm 4$ is not what you think it means or it is not the answer you think it is.   $-89\le \pm 4$ but $\sqrt {16-(-89)^2} = \sqrt{-7905}$ is not a real number.

Answer (score 2):

The domain is $x^{2} \leq 16$ or $|x| \leq 4$ or $-4\leq x \leq 4$.

Note that $\sqrt x$ sign denotes positive square root. The range of $\sqrt {16-x^{2}}$ is $[0,\sqrt {16}]$ or $[0, 4]$. Hence the range of $f$ is $[-4, 0]$.

Comment: sir can you clarify, the circle radius is 4 from the origin, but I am not clear on how the range is determined here

Answer (score 0):

Your notation $x \le \pm 4$ makes no sense.  After all $-500$ thousand billion$ \le \pm 4$ but clearly $x = -500$ thousand billion is neither in the domain of the range.

We need $16-x^2 \ge 0$ so $x^2\le 16$.

Okay..... think about what this means.  If $0 < a < b$ then $a^2 < ab < b^2$.  That's straight forward. but if $b < a < 0$ then $a < 0$ is negative so multiplying by $a$ or $b$ flips the signs.  $b < a$ so $ab > a^2$.  And $b < a$ so $b^2 > ab$ so $a^2 < ab < b^2$.

So if $x^2 \le 16$ and $0 \le x$ then $x \le 4$.

But if $x^2 \le 16$ and $x < 0$ then $-4 < x \iff x^2 < 16$.

So if we have $x^2 \le 16$ that means $-4\le x \le 4$.

....

Oh, I guess the easier way to do it is

if $x^2 \le 16$ then $|x| \le 4$ so $-4 \le -|x|$ and as $x = \pm |x|$ we have $-4 \le x \le 4$.

So that's our domain.

If $-4 \le x \le 4$ then $-4 \le x < 0$ *OR*  $0 \le x \le 4$.

If $-4 \le x < 0$ then $0 < x^2 \le 16$.  And if $0 \le x \le 4$ then $0 \le x^2 \le 16$

Either way we get $0 \le x^2 \le 16$ so $-16 \le -x^2 \le 0$ and $0 \le 16-x^2 \le 16$

And $0 \le \sqrt {16-x^2} \le 4$

And $-4 \le -\sqrt{16-x^2} \le 0$.

So the range is $[-4, 0]$.